# SignalR Connections to Users mapping on multiple Servers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, redis, signalr

I have the following  SignalR Hub, a Redis backplane and a single server.
Its working great like this on one server.
Now I need to run my app on multiple servers and i can not figure out how to map
the users to the connections , so that the  signalR ConnectionId's are shared on both servers.
Maybe a solution would be to store the ConnectionMapping on Redis but i dont know how.
This is how my solution works right now.

MyHub.cs

```
public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        #region Init
        private static IHubContext GetHubContext => GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
  
        public MyHub()
        {
        }
        #endregion Init

        #region Connection Management events
        public Task JoinGroup(string groupName)
        {
            return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
        }

        public Task LeaveGroup(string groupName)
        {
            return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
        }
        [Authorize]
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            if (Context.User != null)
            {
                if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    var userId = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
                    if (userId == 0)
                    {
                        var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<MyUserManager>();
                        var user = userManager.FindByName(Context.User.Identity.Name);
                        if (user != null)
                            userId = user.Id;
                    }
                    var userRoles = UserRoles.GetAll().Where(x => Context.User.IsInRole(x)).ToArray();

                    ConnectionMappingsService.AddConnectionAsync(Context.ConnectionId, userId, userRoles);

                    if (Context.User.IsInRole(UserRoles.Admin))
                        UserStatusChanged(userId, true);
                }
            }
            return base.OnConnected();
        }
        [Authorize]
        public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)

        {
           
            UserDisconnectedAsync(Context.ConnectionId);
            return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }

public static async Task MessageCreatedMobile(int userId)
        {
            var SignalRMessage = new
            {
                ClientEvent = "Message",
                Flag = "Update",
                Target “Test”
            };
            var recipientConnectionIds = await ConnectionMappingsService.GetUserConnectionsAsync(userId);
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();// GetHubContext;
            try
            {
                foreach (var connection in recipientConnectionIds)
                {
                    hubContext.Clients.Client(connection).send(SignalRMessage);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

ConnectionMappingService.cs

```
public static class ConnectionMappingsService
    {
        private static readonly ConnectionMapping<int> UsersConnections = new ConnectionMapping<int>();
        private static readonly ConnectionMapping<string> RoleConnections = new ConnectionMapping<string>();

        public static async Task AddConnectionAsync(string connectionId, int userId, string[] roles)
        {
            var userConnectionTask = UsersConnections.AddAsync(new int[] { userId }, connectionId);
            var roleConnectionTask = RoleConnections.AddAsync(roles, connectionId);
            await Task.WhenAll(userConnectionTask, roleConnectionTask);
        }
        public static async Task AddConnectionIfAbsentAsync(string connectionId, int userId, string[] roles)
        {
            var userConnectionTask = UsersConnections.AddIfAbsentAsync(new int[] { userId }, connectionId);
            var roleConnectionTask=  RoleConnections.AddIfAbsentAsync(roles, connectionId);
            await Task.WhenAll(userConnectionTask, roleConnectionTask);
        }

        public static async Task<ConnectionDataDto> RemoveConnectionAsync(string connectionId)
        {
            var result = new ConnectionDataDto();
            result.UserIds = await UsersConnections.RemoveAsync(connectionId);
            result.Roles = await RoleConnections.RemoveAsync(connectionId);
            return result;
        }

        public static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetUserConnectionsAsync(int userId)
        {
            return await UsersConnections.GetConnectionsAsync(new int[] { userId });
        }
        public static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetUserConnectionsAsync(int[] userIds)
        {
            return await UsersConnections.GetConnectionsAsync(userIds);
        }
        public static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetRoleConnectionsAsync(string[] roles)
        {
            return await RoleConnections.GetConnectionsAsync(roles);
        }

        public static async Task<bool> UserHasConnectionsAsync(int userId)
        {
            return await UsersConnections.AnyConnectionsAsync(userId);
        }
    }
}
```

ConnectionMapping.cs

```
 public class ConnectionMapping<T>
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>> _connections = new Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>>();


        public async Task<int> CountAsync()
        {
            return await Task.Run(()=> Count());
        }
        public async Task AddAsync(T[] keys, string connectionId)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => Add(keys, connectionId));
        }
        public async Task AddIfAbsentAsync(T[] keys, string connectionId)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => AddIfAbsent(keys,connectionId));
        }
        
        public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetConnectionsAsync(T[] keys)
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => GetConnections(keys));
        }
        
        public async Task<T[]> RemoveAsync(string connectionId)
        {
          return await Task.Run(()=>Remove(connectionId) ) ;
        }
        public async Task<T[]> GetConnectionKeysAsync(string connectionId)
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => GetConnectionKeys(connectionId));
        }
        public async Task<bool> AnyConnectionsAsync(T key)
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => AnyConnections(key));
        }


        #region NonAsync
        public int Count()
        {
            lock (_connections)
            {
                return _connections.Count;
            }
        }
        public void Add(T[] keys, string connectionId)
        {
            
            if (keys == null || !keys.Any())
                return;

            lock (_connections)
            {
                foreach (T key in keys)
                {
                    HashSet<string> connections;
                    if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
                    {
                        connections = new HashSet<string>();
                        _connections.Add(key, connections);
                    }

                    lock (connections)
                    {
                        connections.Add(connectionId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void AddIfAbsent(T[] keys, string connectionId)
        {
            if (keys == null || !keys.Any())
                return;

            lock (_connections)
            {
                foreach (T key in keys)
                {
                    HashSet<string> connections;
                    if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
                    {
                        connections = new HashSet<string>();
                        _connections.Add(key, connections);
                    }

                    lock (connections)
                    {
                        if (!connections.Contains(connectionId))
                            connections.Add(connectionId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public IEnumerable<string> GetConnections(T[] keys)
        {
            var result = new HashSet<string>();
            lock (_connections)
            {                
                foreach (var key in keys)
                {
                    HashSet<string> connections;
                    if (_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
                    {
                       result.UnionWith(connections);
                    }
                }
                
            }

            return result as IEnumerable<string>;
        }
        public T[] Remove(string connectionId)
        {
            T[] keys;
            lock (_connections)
            {
                keys = _connections.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(connectionId)).Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
                foreach (var key in keys)
                {
                    HashSet<string> connections;
                    if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    lock (connections)
                    {
                        connections.Remove(connectionId);

                        if (connections.Count == 0)
                        {
                            _connections.Remove(key);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return keys;
        }
        public T[] GetConnectionKeys(string connectionId)
        {
            lock (_connections)
            {
                var keys = _connections.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(connectionId)).Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
                return keys;
            }
        }
        public bool AnyConnections(T key)
        {
            lock (_connections)
            {
                HashSet<string> connections;
                if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return connections.Any();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion NonAsync
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make use of the message queue (rabbit, etc). Each server will have its own connection mappings and when rabbit message arrives, the proper server sends the message to the specific client. Other server will not find connection and do nothing. It is important that message form the queue should be received by all server instances.